# Why do comments have "Delete" instead of the X icon now?

Tags: discussion

I noticed today on Stack Overflow that the `(X)` icon is gone from the end of your comment having been replaced by a red `"Delete"`. Is there a special reason for this?

The `(X)` icon was small and unobtrusive compared to a flashing red `"Delete"` on mouseover.

Is this a permanent change? (any chance to reconsider?)

Comment: Do I just need to close this one? Or `"Delete"` it? (I voted to close it as the dup)

Comment: It doesn't appear that this will be reconsidered, but I wouldn't mind if they made the `Delete` link grey like the old `x`. That way it wouldn't be so distracting when just moving your mouse over your comment

Comment: Or just turn red when you mouseover that bottom corner of the comment. Right now, mouseover anywhere in the comment causes `"Delete"` to flash red. It certainly gets your attention (like fireworks, or someone yelling in a quite room)

Comment: I agree. Especially since on the main site, all the other comment links are blue and the `Delete` button is bright red